# Where is my Rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I paid someone to create a program with Ruby on Rails where it scrapes data and puts it in a Postgres database.  In the program's directory are the standard Rails folders, application, "bin", "config" and other directories.

I'm trying to see a list of the columns in a table. I think the best, or only way, to do this is to log into the actual database, and print it out. I'm trying to use a "psql" command to log in but it is saying:

```
psql: FATAL: database "dan" does not exist
```

I'm not sure where the database is, or how I can find it.

This is what the config/database.yml contains:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: danwork
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: unicode
  username: dan
  password: supersecretpassword

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: sports
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: unicode
  username: namename
  password: sports_db
```

1. Where is my database?
2. How could I find the database on my own using some linux commands, like `find . -iname '...'`?
3. How do I log in, and print out all the columns for the table named "games"?

Comment: There's no development DB? In any case, the prod database is called "sports", indicated by where it says `database: sports` in the config file.

Comment: i am trying the command "psql sports" in the root directory, in the db, and config directories, and it says "FATAL: database sports does not exist"... you are right, there is a development DB, sorry i missed that earlier.  updating my post now

Comment: Have you run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` to actually create the DB? By default you'll be in the `development` environment, where the DB is called `danwork`. *Where* you type in the command is not relevant; `psql` knows nothing of the Rails environment.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this person just created application, but it wasn't run yet, it's just code? In such case you need to create the database (`rake db:create db:migrate`) and then you can connect and check columns

Comment: The dev database is called 'danwork' but you're getting an error saying there's no database called "dan", which sounds like you're entering his username where it expects the database name.  Can you add the postgres command you're using to access the database to your OP?

Comment: @arnvald - he's expecting there to be some actual data, so making a new db using `create` won't help.

Comment: With your update, looks like your development db won't exist. To test just replace the development db details with the production db details. If that works, you'll have to perform `rake db:migrate` as Max said

Answer (score 2):

You want `rails dbconsole` or `rails db`.

From the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/command_line.html#rails-dbconsole):

> `rails dbconsole` figures out which database you’re using and drops you into whichever command line interface you would use with it (and figures out the command line parameters to give to it, too!). It supports MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite and SQLite3.
>
> You can also use the alias “db” to invoke the dbconsole: `rails db`.

To see the contents of your `games` table:

```
~/Documents/workspace/<project-dir>$ rails db
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.

development=# select * from games;
 id | date | description |         city         | state 
----+------+-------------+----------------------+-------
  1 |      |             | Boston               | MA
  2 |      |             | Seattle              | WA
(2 rows)

development=# \q
~/Documents/workspace/<project-dir>$
```

---

If you *really* want to use `psql -U <username> <dbname>`, you can find these parameters as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4197278/5236093) and paraphrased here:

```
~/Documents/workspace/<project-dir>$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.4)
2.3.1 :001 > Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
 => {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"development"} 
2.3.1 :002 > exit
~/Documents/workspace/<project-dir>$ psql development
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.

development=# \q
~/Documents/workspace/<project-dir>$
```

As you can see, if no username is returned, you won't need the `-U` flag.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your database is running on a server independent of Rails (it will be set up by your coder). It looks like your database is on your localhost.
2. It will be dependent on your server OS.
3. If you're looking to show column names in your database, you'll be able to [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575970/activerecord-list-columns-in-table-from-console) in the Rails Console:

   ```
   $ rails c
   $ Game.column_names
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To access your database using plain PostgreSQL

```
su username
psql
\db database_name;
```

Comment: What a roundabout way of doing it. If you're using password auth, simply `psql -U username dbname`. If you're using `peer` auth, `sudo -u username psql dbname`.

Answer (score 0):

To connect with `psql`, you must specify the database name.

If you're using password auth, simply `psql -U username dbname`.

If you're using `peer` auth, `sudo -u username psql dbname`.

In your case you seem to be using password auth and connecting to the local host, so I suggest:

```
psql -U dan danwork
```

and entering the password when prompted. (You can use a `~/.pgpass` file to save the password if desired; see the pgpass documentation)